# How to prefix SASS blocks with a specific scope ID via mixin

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

Looking to be able to add the app scope id to my sass files when we have multiple apps reusing class names.

That way I can have the following definition:

```
$app-scope-id: 'appOne';
```

And then write my SCSS in that app

```
.blockName{
    background: blue;
    &__element{
        color: orange;
    }
}
```

And call a mixin or something else to just go

```
@include prefixMixin(){
    .blockName{
        background: blue;
        &__element{
           color: orange;
        }
    }
}
```

And that render out css like:

```
.appOne-blockName{ background: blue; }
.appOne-blockName__element{ color: orange }
```

I'm aware I can use interpolation at the beginning of my block, but was hoping I could keep it cleaner with just a mixin call where necessary and only call it once for an entire SASS file if I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do what you want with SASS. You could maybe do something like this:

```
$app-scope-id: 'appOne';

@mixin prefix($selectorType: ".") {
    @at-root {
        #{$selectorType}#{$app-scope-id}-#{&} {
            @content;
        }
    }
}

blockName {
    @include prefix() {
        background: blue;
        &__element{
            color: orange;
        }
    }
}
```

Which compiles as:

```
.appOne-blockName { background: blue; }
.appOne-blockName__element { color: orange; }
```

But you would still need to include it for each selector that needs the prefix. I'm not sure this can be called "clean" either.