# How to add a prefix (prepend a name) to an entire module imported with @use in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I have a simple question but I can't seem to figure this out.

Suppose I have one file with the following contents:

**icons.scss**

```scss
.icon {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;

    &[data-icon="left"] {
        background-image: url('...');
    }
    &[data-icon="right"] {
        background-image: url('...');
    }
}
```

This would compiles to:

```css
.icon {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
}
.icon[data-icon=left] {
    background-image: url('...');
}
.icon[data-icon=right] {
    background-image: url('...');
}
```

Then I also have another file which is the main file where I import all other files inside before compiling.

**main.scss**

```scss
@use "./icons.scss";
@use "./some-other-file.scss";
```

What I would like to do is prepend all the classes imported from `"icons.scss"` or any other files with a name of my choice. For example, `.icon` would become `.prefixed-icon` and so on.

This is my desired result:

**Desired result:**

```css
.prefixed-icon {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
}
.prefixed-icon[data-icon=left] {
    background-image: url('...');
}
.prefixed-icon[data-icon=right] {
    background-image: url('...');
}
```

I've only started learning SASS earlier today so this got way over my head. I tried to use the `sass:selector` and `sass:meta` build-in modules but didn't manage to figure it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prefix SASS blocks with a specific scope ID via mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68399722/how-to-prefix-sass-blocks-with-a-specific-scope-id-via-mixin)

Comment: This might work, but how can I use it with files imported with @use?